# Access UICollectionView cells in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have added some buttons to a UICollectionView like so in the storyboard:

[image]

When I build the app, I don't see anything in the UICollectionView. Why is this? I want to have only 5 buttons in there and receive their click events in the view controller. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you need to implement `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` and `numberOfItemsInSection` cos no matter how many cell you put in collectionview if you dont implement those delegate nothing will show

Comment: with this two methods mentioned above you need to implement `cellForItemAtIndexPath` also

Comment: What do I put in these two functions? There are 5 buttons, so is it 1 section and 5 items in section? And what do I put in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

Each cell behaves like a button. So in my storyboard I put one reusable cell with a label in it, and I add 5 items to the `UICollectionView` and it worked as expected.